# enable jquery slideToggle() work for multiple outputs that comes from a while

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have the following piece of code in php where I was trying to apply jquery slideToggle() for each youtube video presentation. My problem is that jquery slideToggle() works only for my first youtube video presentation inside my while statement. The rest of them are not working. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<style>
#flip
{
padding:0px;
}

#panel
{
width:475px;
margin-left:3px;
margin-bottom:5px;
padding:4px;
display:none;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 30, 10, 2.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);
background-color:#363636;
}   
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>


<?php

// above code

//next starts the while and outputs from my table all rows that contains users posts
// my code outputs all youtube links in a presentation format

while(){    


 $row['comment'] = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i", "</br>

<div id='panel'>
<object width=\"0px;\" height=\"0px;\">
    <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/$1&hl=en&fs=1\"></param>
    <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param>
    <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/$1&hl=en&fs=1?&autoplay=1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"475px;\" height=\"260px;\"></embed>
</object>       
</div>

 <table style='border:1px solid lightgrey;'>
 <td bgcolor='#EBEBEB' style='vertical-align:top;'>                 
   <div id='flip' style='cursor:pointer;'>
   <div id='container'><div id='img1'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$1/default.jpg'/></div><div id='img2'><img src='img/play-button.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;'/> </div></div>
   </div>
 </td>

 <td width='355px;' bgcolor='#EBEBEB' style='vertical-align:top;'>
  <font color='#363636'><b>$video_title</b></font><font color='#545454'></br><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$id}' target='_blank'><font color='#69aa35'><b>Youtube.com</b></font></a> - $video_perigrafh...</font><font color='#949494'>[$view_count views]</font>
 </td>
 </table>", $row['comment']);


 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an id (#panel) and id's are supposed to be unique. The selector is based on the native GetElementByID, which returns the first match.

You should use a class (`<div class="panel">`) instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLXLr/ - illustration of the id vs class targeting

Edit: regarding the new code with classes, if your HTML is:

```
<div class='panel'>
    ...
</div>
<table style='border:1px solid lightgrey;'>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor='#EBEBEB' style='vertical-align:top;'>
            <div class='flip' style='cursor:pointer;'>
                ..
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code for the toggle should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('table').prev('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

You can adjust it to fit your needs , of course.

Comment: ok thanks I have changed it to class. Now the problem is that if I click on first video slidetoggled all and not only the certain video. The same happens if I click on the rest videos. Any idea how it should slidetoggle only the certain video?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your excellent script. You saved me a lot of time. This will help a lot of people by looking at it!

Comment: the following piece of code works perfect with chrome. The only problem is that on IE when slide up, it does not automatically stop playing the video. Any idea how to fix this?